# Edit Option in Tableau server

Tags: tableau-api

My users are asking for the EDIT option to be provided in the Tableau server. Please advise:

- If providing EDIT capability to the user is a good practise.
- If EDIT capability is provided to the user, can it be made such that the user can edit the report but not overwrite the current report. Rather they can save it to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

Providing end users the webedit ability can be good practice, but it depends on what the end goal for the users is. I wouldn't recommend building dashboards in Tableau Server webedit, but editing already published dashboards should be fine. Please keep in mind that Tableau Server webedit does not have the same 1:1 functionality as Tableau Desktop.

[Web Authoring and Tableau Desktop Feature Comparison](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/server_desktop_web_edit_differences.html)

To answer the second question about editing and not overwriting the current report. I would check out custom views, should be exactly what your looking for.

[Custom Views](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/customview.html)